# How to create solid guage chart?

Tags: highcharts

I need to create a solid gauge chart.

Is there anyway to achieve this requirement using highcharts? We are using 4.0.1 version

Thanks in advance

Comment: I achieve this requirement using highcharts, But it's not good.. http://jsfiddle.net/hy2xyq0x/

Comment: Modify center position to 50% / 50% then chart will be printed properly. http://jsfiddle.net/hy2xyq0x/1/

Comment: How to increase/decrease the thickness of the fill area (green color)?

Comment: By innerRadius param, http://jsfiddle.net/hy2xyq0x/2/

Comment: Thanks :)  http://jsfiddle.net/hy2xyq0x/3/